# How do Morphling's replicants work?

Tags: dota-2

I know that he can replicate another hero, and that the skills of that hero are available to you. What I don't understand is (and I've tried googling this but I can't find definitive answers for this patch)

- how do skills work? Say you replicate Lich, and you drop a chain frost on the enemy team, does it do full damage? Does whether on which items the replicated Lich had i.e. whether he had Agh's Scepter or not?
- how much right click damage does the replicant do, 50%?
- how long do the replicants last?
- how much damage can replicants take?
- does anyone have a good, detailed guide on how to play his replicants? Note - I'm not asking you for how to use replicants, just for any pre-existing guides - though if you have any key tips to effective replication I'd love to hear them!!

Again, appreciate this is out there on google, but I can't find anything that answers all of these for latest patch, so any info you've got would be helpful!

Thanks all!!

Comment: No, you don't have access to the replicant's skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicate, Morphling's ultimate, lets you create an illusion of the target ally or enemy hero. The illusion lasts 30/45/60 seconds at level 1/2/3, deals 50% of the original target's damage, and takes 100% damage. When the illusion is still alive, Morphling can activate Replicate again to instantly take the place of the illusion (although destroying it in the process). The secondary ability allows you to effectively split push with Morphling, as you can send the illusion to your own fountain or to another lane to quickly move around the map.

One important thing to note is that you can't cast Replicate on yourself, although if you're facing a Shadow Demon and he disrupts you, you can use Replicate on one of those illusions of yourself to get a full strength illusion.

Comment: Great, thanks Kotsu! Do you know any good guides to using them in real games?

Comment: I would honestly just look up any highly rated Morphling guide. Like I briefly mentioned in my answer, the most effective use of replicate is to use it as a split pushing mechanism. The easiest use of it is to replicate the highest damaging carry in the game, so you can have two of them.